# C# Pointers of managed types

Tags: c#, .net, managed

Depending on a parameter in my method, I would like to change different variables in my class and act on them.  In C++ this is super easy, but in C# it seems more difficult without a lot of if/else statements.  Is there a better way to do this in C#?

In C++ it would look something like (its been a few years since I coded in C++ so be kind):

```
void MyMethod(int option)
{
    int* _i;
    string* _s;
    MyClass* _mc; // My created class
    DataGridViewColumn _col; // Managed class

    if(option == 0)
    {
        _i = &m_SomeInt;
        _s = &m_SomeStr;
        _mc = &m_SomeMC;
        _col = &m_SomeCol;
    }
    else if(option == 1)
    {
        _i = &m_SomeOtherInt;
        _s = &m_SomeOtherStr;
        _mc = &m_SomeOtherMC;
        _col = &m_SomeOtherCol;
    }

    // Now I can act on _i, _s, etc and Im really acting on the member variables.
    _i = 5;
    _s = "Changed String";
    .....
}
```

This is what I want to do, but in C#. But this is my solution and its messy at the end:

```
void MyMethod(int option)
{
    int _i;
    string _s;
    MyClass _mc; // My created class
    DataGridViewColumn _col; // Managed class

    if(option == 0)
    {
        _i = m_SomeInt;
        _s = m_SomeStr;
        _mc = m_SomeMC;
        _col = m_SomeCol;
    }
    else if(option == 1)
    {
        _i = m_SomeOtherInt;
        _s = m_SomeOtherStr;
        _mc = m_SomeOtherMC;
        _col = m_SomeOtherCol;
    }

    _i = 5;
    _s = "Changed String";
    .....

    if(option == 0)
    {
        m_SomeInt = _i;
        m_SomeStr = _s;
        m_SomeMC = _mc;
        m_SomeCol = _col;
    }
    else if(option == 1)
    {
        m_SomeOtherInt = _i;
        m_SomeOtherStr = _s;
        m_SomeOtherMC = _mc;
        m_SomeOtherCol = _col;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean? Why don't you simply do the same in C#? Using pointers isn't necessary even in C++ (references are the preferred way)

Comment: And why not to do changes on properties without intermediate variables?

Comment: [Ref returns and ref locals](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/06/23/ref-returns-and-ref-locals.aspx) "the CLR type system supports additional usages of "ref", though C# does not. The CLR type system also allows methods to return refs to variables, and allows local variables to be aliases for other variables"

Comment: Easiest would be to wrap those four properties in a class and then pass instances of that class around. They you can just do `p.SomeInt = i;` `p.SomeStr = s;` etc.

Comment: Apart from using pointers instead of references, the C++ code is a smell. Using options and variables as aliases sounds like [a parameter object](https://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/introduce-parameter-object) is hidden behind the fields and the variables

Comment: What if this is needed in a .NET callback method and you do not control the parameters?

Comment: What do you mean and why would it matter? Not that you can't cover this eg by using a constructor. For that matter, why pass an option parameter instead of using overloading in C++? This is C design, not C++

Comment: I suppose I can create another method passing in the arguments needed.

Answer (score 3):

In C# you need to wrap them up in a container and you choose between the two containers

```
class DataContainer
{
    public int I {get; set;}
    public string S {get;set;}
    public MyClass Mc {get;set;}
    public DataGridViewColumn Col {get;set;}
}

void MyMethod(int option)
{
    DataContainer container;    

    if(option == 0)
    {
        container = m_SomeContainer;
    }
    else if(option == 1)
    {
        container = m_SomeOtherContainer;
    }
    else
    {
         throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(option));
    }

    container.I = 5;
    container.S = "Changed String";
    .....

}
```

A even better option is don't take in a option and instead pass in the container class itself.

```
void MyMethod(DataContainer container)
{
    container.I = 5;
    container.S = "Changed String";
    .....

}
```

Comment: You don't *need* to do this, it's a better design both for C++ and C#. It even has a name - the Paremeter Object refactoring. Options means there is probably an inheritance hidden in there - or the `SomeOtherContainer` is superfluous

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you can just reverse the logic to reduce code duplication:

```
void MyMethod(int option)
{
    int i = 5;
    string s = "Changed String";
    MyClass* _mc = /* not sure what goes here */
    DataGridViewColumn _col = /* not sure what goes here */

    if(option == 0)
    {
        m_SomeInt = i;
        m_SomeStr = s;
        m_SomeMC = mc;
        m_SomeCol = col;
    }
    else if(option == 1)
    {
        m_SomeOtherInt = i;
        m_SomeOtherStr = s;
        m_SomeOtherMC = mc;
        m_SomeOtherCol = col;
    }

}
```

Or you could create a class that contains the values you want to change and use a reference to *that*.  Then you don't need to have two different *sets* of variables - you have two different variables that each reference a class that encapsulates those values.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you.  I have used all your answers and created the following (Names have been changed to protect the innocent):

```
class DataContainer
{
    public int I {get; set;}
    public string S {get;set;}
    public MyClass Mc {get;set;}
    public DataGridViewColumn Col {get;set;}
}

void MyMethod(int option)
{
    DataContainer container;    

    if(option == 0)
    {
        Helper(new DataContainer(m_SomeInt, ...));
    }
    else if(option == 1)
    {
        Helper(new DataContainer(m_SomeOtherInt, ...));
    }
    else
    {
         throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(option));
    }
}

void Helper(DataContainer container)
{
        container.I = 5;
        container.S = "Changed String";
        .....
}
```